How can an attacker will be able to access my cloud firestore database, If I have not setup any cloud firestore security rules
Example:
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "project-number",
    "project_id": "project-id",
    "storage_bucket": "project-storage-bucket"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "mobilesdk_app_id",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.sample"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "client_id..apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "api_key"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}


I am building an Android app that will be using Cloud Firestore. I know that an attacker can decompile the app and get the google-services.json file.
But then how will they know the database details like database ID etc?

Your question says, the title: "How can an attacker will be able to access my cloud firestore database, If I have not setup any cloud firestore security rules?"  Yet, the question goes on to show the rules you have set.  Every Firestore database created through the Firebase console has security rules, even if you didn't set them yourself.
Your rules, in particular, match all documents in all subcollections (match /{document=**}) and allow full read/write access to all of those documents (allow read, write: if true).

I know that an attacker can decompile the app and get the google-services.json file. But then how will they know the database details like database ID etc?

With Firestore, the ID of the default database is the same as the ID of your project.  That ID is sitting right there in the google-service.json file you mentioned.  In your fake example, the project ID is "project-id".  This is public information once your app is published, as is all of the instructions your app contains that accesses Firestore documents.  Someone with your public source code (or just watching the network access of your app) can know the names of all the collections your app accesses.
Using only the project ID and the names of documents and collection, anyone can use the Firebase SDK to reproduce that access.  All they have to do is intitialize the Firesbase SDK with the same contents as the public google-service.json.  Or, they could even use the Firestore REST API to directly access your database contents without needing any SDK at all.
If you don't want your database to be fully public like this, you will need to spend time integrating security tools like Firebase Authentication, Firebase App Check, and good security rules that limit access to the database to only the authenticated users who should have access.

Thank you for your answer! just one more question what if I'll create a database (i.e. not use the default one)? will then as well only the project id will be sufficient for the attacker to gain access?

Any attacker will be able to take the information in your public code and configuration to access the database. It doesn't matter what combination of information is required - it will all be there for them to see.  It's not possible to hide it the required information if your database logic is in the app itself.  The only way to hide this data is not to put it in your app at all, and instead make your app go through a backend that performs the queries.  At that point, you need security for your backend endpoint.  Security is hard.

If you're using these rules:
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

It means that you allow anybody who knows your project ID to read/write to/from your Firestore database. Which is obviously bad, since malicious users can take advantage of it.
So someone who knows only your project ID can produce write and read operations. This means that your bills will increase.
It’s true that you can use these settings for a small amount of time for testing purposes, but never in a production environment. So always write the proper rules along with implementing Firebase App Check which:

protects your API resources from abuse by preventing unauthorized clients from accessing your backend resources.


If I know your project ID, I can do exactly what you can do, you being the owner of the project. Your database is publically accessible to everybody in the world. The operations of reading and writing can be performed using one of the available SDKs, for web or mobile, or using the Cloud Firestore REST API.
